# I am having an issue fitting a log offset in lme4's glmer

Tags: r, offset, lme4

So I am trying to predict fit an offset using the log of time in lme4's glmer. I am running into an issue where I get the error message:

> Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate

This is my code:

```r
direct <- fixef(glmer(lmdth ~ sex + gf + agec10 + ht + 
   smk + diab + pvd + offpump + 
   statin + gsum + agsum + LAD + seq + (1|trial), 
   offset = log(lmdthdays), 
   data = sampledata,         
  family = binomial(link="logit")))[2]
```

This error message persists even by removing covariates and attempting to run the model using `allFit` and trying all optimizers.

I have also tried using `log(lmdthdays)` without offset and it will run fine, it also runs fine without `offset(())`, so the issue arises when I use offset. I have also tried putting offset this way, however it has not helped. I have also tried using `nAGQ = 20` which has not made a difference and also tried manually using optimizers like NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD to no effect:

```r
direct <- fixef(glmer(lmdth ~ sex + gf + agec10 + ht + 
    smk + diab + pvd + offpump + 
    statin + gsum + agsum + LAD + seq + 
  offset(log(lmdthdays)) + (1|trial), 
  data = sampledata,  
  family = binomial(link = "logit")))[2]
```

This is the context:

```r
for(i in 1:ntrials-1) {
   ntrials <- 2000
   npat <- 4413
   sampledata <- mgfipdma1t2346[sample(nrow(mgfipdma1t2346),
      npat, replace=TRUE),]
 direct <- fixef(glmer(lmdth ~ sex + gf + agec10 +
    ht + smk + diab + pvd + offpump + statin +
    gsum + agsum + LAD + seq + (1|trial), 
    offset=log(lmdthdays), data=sampledata, 
    family=binomial(link="logit")))[2]
 total <- fixef(glmer(lmdth ~ sex + agec10 + ht + 
     smk + diab + pvd + offpump + statin + gsum + 
     agsum + LAD + seq + (1|trial), 
    offset=log(lmdthdays), data=sampledata, 
       family=binomial(link="logit")))[2]
 indirect2 <- exp(total-direct)
 indirect <- rbind(indirect, indirect2)
}
```

I am ultimately trying to run a mediation analysis using this logistic regression, but I am trying to account for the variation in time to event (in this case death) in my data. Since this is a pooled analysis of multiple trials, I also want to adjust for trial level variability.

Would appreciate any help I can get, I don't know what steps to take to troubleshoot this next.

Comment: Easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(sampledata)`, if that is not too large. The error may occur for several reasons: often transforming the data leads to NaN values. Also your model looks rather complex with lots of terms, which may be an issue.

Comment: > str(mgfipdma1t2346$lmdth)
 num [1:2712] NA NA 0 NA NA NA 0 NA NA 0 ... The data is 0s and 1s but there are a significant number of NAs because that data is missing, so around 25% of the data is missing for that variable, for most other variables there is little to no missing data.  > summary(mgfipdma1t2346$lmdth)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0582  0.0000  1.0000     580

Comment: does it fail immediately or does it only fail for some samples? (Also, a log offset is a bit odd for a logit link -- a cloglog link would probably make more sense, although it also makes the numerics a little bit more fragile ...)

Comment: It fails immediately for me, the issue occurs purely when I add this offset, if I do not add the offset, or just add log(lmdthdays) then it runs fine.

Comment: direct <- fixef(glmer(lmdth ~ sex + gf + offset(log(lmdthdays)) + (1|trial), control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)), nAGQ=20, data=sampledata, family=binomial("logit")))[2] If I try this, it makes no difference, gives me the same error

Comment: Adding cloglog helped with this code (i.e. the direct), but not the (total), so I think the cloglog does make a difference somewhat.  direct <- fixef(glmer(lmdth ~ sex + gf + offset(log(lmdthdays)) + (1|trial), control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)), nAGQ=20, data=sampledata, family=binomial("cloglog")))[2]

Comment: I see that you've also posted this question [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/RStudio/comments/16b3jzs/using_offset_in_lme4s_glmer_and_getting_an_error/). I don't think we can solve the problem without a reproducible example. Can you post a link?